# Is this patent still valid/enforceable? If the owner of a patent has failed to pay their maintenance dues, will the filed patent reflect that?

Tags: filing

In reference to the patent: [US8276282](https://www.google.com/patents/US8276282)

Is this patent still valid/enforceable? If the owner of a patent has failed to pay their maintenance dues, will the filed patent reflect that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it appears that this patent is still enforceable.

If you check the USPTO's [Public PAIR](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) for this patent, you can see that its current status is "Patented Case", meaning that it is still valid and has not lapsed for failure to pay maintenance fees. If you're interested in seeing more information about future maintenance fees due for this patent, you can use [this USPTO tool](https://ramps.uspto.gov/eram/getMaintFeesInfo.do) to look it up (you'll need both the patent number, 8276282, and the application number (without the usual punctuation), 13114175).